# How do I make a query in cloudant-python selecting an specific field?

Tags: python, cloudant, python-cloudant

I'm trying to make a query that selects only one of the fields/attributes. The query should result in something like an array of a nameField or a numberField, or even a single variable, what I want is to separate the values so I can manipulate it in the app

I already tried using `"query = cloudant.query.Query(myDatabaseDemo, fields=['nameField'])`" but the result when I print query is just "`fields=['nameField']`".

```
from cloudant.result import Result, ResultByKey

...

client = Cloudant(serviceUsername, servicePassword, url=serviceURL)
myDatabaseDemo = client.create_database(databaseName)

...

result_collection = Result(myDatabaseDemo.all_docs, include_docs=True)
print ("document:\n{0}\n".format(result_collection[0]))
```

The actual code results in a set of values, like a json document

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Cloudant query](https://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/query.html)? It allows you to specify `fields (list) – A list of fields to be returned by the query.`